# MongoDB find if all array elements are in the other bigger array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have an array of id's of LEGO parts in a LEGO building.

```
// building collection
{
   "name": "Gingerbird House",
   "buildingTime": 45,
   "rating": 4.5,
   "elements": [
     {
       "_id": 23,
       "requiredElementAmt": 14
     },
     {
       "_id": 13,
       "requiredElementAmt": 42
     }
   ]
}
```

and then

```
//elements collection
 {
 "_id": 23,
 "name": "blue 6 dots brick",
 "availableAmt":20
 }

 {
 "_id": 13,
 "name": "red 8 dots brick",
 "availableAmt":50
 }
 {"_id":254,
 "name": "green 4 dots brick",
 "availableAmt":12
 }
```

How can I find it's possible to build a building? I.e. database will return the building only if the "elements" array in a building document consists of those elements that I have in a warehouse(elements collection) require less(or equal) amount of certain element.

In SQL(which from I came recently) I would write something like`SELECT * FROM building WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT fk_building FROM building_elemnt_amt WHERE fk_element NOT IN (1, 3))`
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont pretend I get how it works in SQL without any comparison, but in mongodb you can do something like that:

```
db.buildings.find({/* building filter, if any */}).map(function(b){
    var ok = true;
    b.elements.forEach(function(e){
        ok = ok && 1 == db.elements.find({_id:e._id, availableAmt:{$gt:e.requiredElementAmt}}).count();
    })
    return ok ? b : false;
}).filter(function(b){return b});
```

or

```
db.buildings.find({/* building filter, if any */}).map( function(b){
    var condition = [];
    b.elements.forEach(function(e){
        condition.push({_id:e._id, availableAmt:{$gt:e.requiredElementAmt}});
    })
    return db.elements.find({$or:condition}).count() == b.elements.length ? b : false;
}).filter(function(b){return b});
```

The last one should be a bit quicker, but I did not test. If performance is a key, it must be better to mapReduce it to run subqueries in parallel.

Note: The examples above work with assumption that `buildings.elements` have no elements with the same id. Otherwise the array of `elements` needs to be pre-processed before `b.elements.forEach` to calculate total `requiredElementAmt` for non-unique ids.

#### EDIT: How it works:

Select all/some documents from `buildings` collection with [find](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/):

`db.buildings.find({/* building filter, if any */})`

returns a cursor, which we iterate with [map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) applying the function to each document:

`map(function(b){...})`

The function itself iterates over `elements` array for each `buildings` document `b`:

`b.elements.forEach(function(e){...})`

and [find](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) [number](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) of documents in `elements` collection for each element e

`db.elements.find({_id:e._id, availableAmt:{$gte:e.requiredElementAmt}}).count();`

which match a condition:

```
elements._id == e._id
and
elements.availableAmt >= e.requiredElementAmt
```

until first request that return 0.

Since `elements._id` is unique, this subquery returns either 0 or 1. 
First 0 in expression `ok = ok && 1 == 0` turns `ok` to false, so rest of the `elements` array will be iterated without touching the db.

The function returns either current `buildings` document, or false:

`return ok ? b : false`

So result of the [map](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/) function is an array, containing full `buildings` documents which can be built, or false for ones that lacks at least 1 resource.

Then we [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) this array to get rid of `false` elements, since they hold no useful information:

`filter(function(b){return b})`

It returns a new array with all elements for which `function(b){return b}` doesn't return `false`, i.e. only full `buildings` documents.

Comment: Alex, thank you very much for your answer, but could you please explain what the `.filter(function(b){return b});` does? I didn't find any information about it online.

Comment: It's just javascript `Array.filter()`. I have updated the answer with some explanations.